# How can moderators, site helpers, and administrators become more noticeable on this site?

Tags: feature-request

Seriously, without going to the user's profile, these people look like everybody else. Maybe moderators should have color-coded names or have special profile pictures or speak in a distinct dialect or anything that makes them more recognizable from everyone else, so that it's easier to contact a moderator about a problematic user or post.

Comment: They should have hats. And robes. And sticks with curvy ends, like a shepherd's.

Comment: Okay, so someone who doesn't notice the diamonds asks if there were a way to identify mods, and two people who very well know that the tiny diamonds ID mods downvote the question.   Bad voting!

Answer (score 9):

First of all, we already have a diamond next to our name. Nobody else does. That is our mark. In chat, we have blue names in addition to the diamond.

Second, we are list in [a special tab](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) on the sites we moderate.

Third, you don't really need to know who we are at all in order to "contact a moderator". **You don't need to find the right person, all you need to do is use the flag tool**. That automatically gets ahold of the right people for you. That's it's purpose. When you find a problematic post, flag it. Problematic "users" aren't something you need to find, such users are identified by a repeating pattern of problematic posts which is not something you need to worry about. Other people have the tools for that job, you just flag problematic posts.

Lastly, maybe we want to blend in sometimes! Maybe we are just people to, users of this site just like everybody else except with extra responsibilities when it comes time to make a judgement call in exceptional situations.

Comment: Finally made the 20K club! Good Work!

Comment: Yeah, flagging is how you get a hold of mods. There really is nothing else you need.